# Getting InflationException for line 21

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

Below is the error I am getting while executing my program. I tried a few solutions which were given on stack overflow, but I am unable to figure out the problem. Can someone please be kind enough to help me?

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/contact_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                    android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/call_description"
                android:id="@+id/call_button"
                android:src="@drawable/call"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

```css
package com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm.R;
import com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm.objects.Contact;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by kalap on 20-03-2016.
 */
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;

    public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> contactList, Activity activity) {
        this.contactList = contactList;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_contact_row, parent, false);
        return new ContactViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.name.setText(contactList.get(position).getName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(contactList.get(position).getPhoneNumber());
        holder.callButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(contactList.get(position).getPhoneNumber().isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Phone number does not exist",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + contactList.get(position).getPhoneNumber()));
                    try {
                        activity.startActivity(call);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        Log.e("TTM_Error", e.getMessage());
                        Snackbar.make(view,"Permission to call not given",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;
        private TextView phoneNumber;
        private ImageView callButton;
        private CardView contactCard;

        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            callButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
            contactCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_card);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm, PID: 955
                                                                            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                at com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm.adapters.ContactAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:39)
                                                                                at com.example.kalap.contacts_ttm.adapters.ContactAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:25)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5464)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4689)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2600)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16508)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1955)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1152)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1334)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1039)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread
```

Comment: The problem is in layout file `R.layout.custom_contact_row`. Post your layout file `custom_contact_row`

Comment: The first xml code is the layout file

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, it happened due to the textSize given in TextView, i.e. ?Android one. I removed them and hard-coded the size to resolve the issue.